# Why is the "required" HTML attribute is not working?

Tags: html, css, forms, button, bootstrap-4

As the heading suggests, the required attribute is not working, so I cannot seem to be able to validate my form.

I am creating an event registration form.

I have tried encapsulating each element inside form,but that doesn't seem to work.

What can I do to help with that? Please excuse me if the question is childish. I am a beginner, and I am trying to practice as much as I can.

......................................................................................................................................................

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
 * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
text-danger {
    color: #e74c3c;
}
input[type=text], select, textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  resize: horizontal;
}
legend {
font: bold 1.0em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #00008B;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
label {
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 0;
  display: inline-block;

  }

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

.container {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
}
fieldset {
border: 1px solid #61B5CF;
margin-top: 1.4em;
padding: 0.6em;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 600px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .col-25, .col-75, input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}
input:not([type=submit]):invalid {
    background-color: #ffdddd;
}

input:not([type=submit]):valid {
    background-color: #ddffdd;
}

input:not([type=submit]):invalid:required {
    background: #ffdddd url('http://www.developerdrive.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/asterisk1.png') no-repeat right top; 
}

input:not([type=submit]):valid:required {
    background: #ddffdd url('http://www.developerdrive.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/asterisk1.png') no-repeat right top; 
}

input:not([type=submit]):optional {
    background-color: #add1ef;
}
/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2> WIE ILS'19 Registration</h2>

  <form novalidate="">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Login Details</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">E-Mail</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
    <input name="email" placeholder="E-Mail Address" class="form-control"  type="text" required>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br></br>

    <!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-2 control-label" >Password</label> 
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" onchange='check_pass();' required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br></br>
<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-2 control-label" >Confirm Password</label> 
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" onchange='check_pass();' required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br></br>

  </form>
</fieldset>
<form>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Personal Information</legend>

<form>
  <div  class="form-group">
  <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">First Name</label>  
  <div class="col-md-3 inputGroupContainer">
  <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input  name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control"  type="text" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>

<br></br>
<!-- Text input-->
<form>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Last Name</label> 
    <div class="col-md-3 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control"  type="text" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
<br></br>
<!-- Text input-->
<form>     
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Contact No.</label>  
    <div class="col-md-3 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
  <input name="contact_no" placeholder="(+92)" class="form-control" type="text" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
<br></br>
<form>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-2 control-label">CNIC No.</label> 

    <div class="col-md-3 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input name="contact_no" placeholder="No-Hyphens" class="form-control" type="text" id="message" required>
   <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
<br></br>
</fieldset>  
  </form>

<form novalidate="">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Education Details</legend>
<form>
  <div  class="form-group">
  <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">University/Institute</label>  
  <div class="col-md-3 inputGroupContainer">
  <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-education"></i></span>
  <input  name="first_name" placeholder="Institute Name" class="form-control"  type="text" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>

<br></br>
<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Degree Program </label> 
    <div class="col-md-3 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control"  type="text" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br></br>
<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Semester</label>  
    <div class="col-md-3 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></i></span>
  <input name="contact_no" placeholder="" class="form-control" type="text" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br></br>

</fieldset>  
  </form>
<form novalidate="">
<h5 style="font-weight:bold" >Do you need accomodation?</h5>
  <label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
<br>
<br>
    <button type="submit" name="submit"  value="registration"  id="submit" disabled>Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
<script >
    function check_pass() {
    if (document.getElementById('password').value ==
            document.getElementById('confirm_password').value) {
        document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;
    }
}
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the submit to work, you **need** to put it inside of the form that you would like to submit. There are other ways of doing it, but that usually incorporates JavaScript and JQuery. The reason it is preventing you from submitting when it is inside the form though, is due to the `novalidate` attribute on the form. Just remove that and you should be good to go!

P.S. Even though the field is required on the front-end, that is all client side so it's not hard to go in and change it. It's always a good idea to validate it on the back-end as well. Think of the front-end as more of a suggestion and less of a final verdict.